# Android Emulator or Android Phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I hope you're all good. I am working on an android application project and I mostly use android emulator for testing the application. Android Emulator takes too much time for application loading and since I am working on the design I have to run the application after a few seconds again and again. Because of slow emulator I think my time is wasted and I can't focus on the work.

I recently tried my Galaxy Note for running application and its quite fast and running experience is much better. What I wanted to know is.. Does running eclipse project on my Phone will harm my mobile phone in any way?
Because moments back while using the phone the screen got stuck and the icons changed to different green, red and blue color. I restarted the phone and its acting normal now. But I wanted to know if it happened because of the eclipse project running on the phone? Is it safe ?

Comment: It is supposed to be safe, but it seems like you triggered a bug in the android build on that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to harm your phone.

Apart from the wear and tear (YMMV) of repeatedly flashing your app to memory you may unwittingly (or otherwise) create a virus.

I've been in a situation where a thread has run amok after the app terminated and hogged the processor slowing things down. It did eventually quit though (possibly after elective rebooting). I've often had my phone restart when debugging on it. I wouldn't worry too much about that (although my domain was Samsung's bada, a lot less robust platform).

I don't see too many risks with Java apps as the language is so well managed. Native code is a risk in that, at least, a buffer overflow could place unwanted code outside of the process address space and so escape being cleaned up when the app quits. A shut down and/or force close may result from such errors.

Comment: On Android, the most I can think of is the wear and tear of constantly flashing the app. Still, one would assume it won't be enough to break the flash storage, considering the general life time of a device and the general write cycles of the flash memory.